# Finding average error

Tags: measurement-error, error-propagation

Consider the following data:

20 +- 2, 25+-1, 30+- 3, 40+-1

If I have to find the average error, I can follow two methods:

1. (2 + 1 + 3 + 1)/4 = 1.75
2. Sqrt (4 + 1+ 9 + 1 )= 3.9

Since, (20 + 25 + 30 + 40) = 115/4

So the final answer is:

115/4 +- 1.75 OR 115/4 +- 3.9.

Which method is correct? Any views, please?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=combine+error+score%3A2

Comment: My question is rather simple while the link @whuber shared gave so many detailed posts. Unfortunately, none explains my simple example. Could you specify anyone?

Comment: In statistics, a simple answer to a simple question is likely a wrong one.  One message conveyed by all those posts is that your question is ambiguous: what do you hope the $\pm$ value will represent?  Since your data are widely varied--they range from around $20$ to around $40$--what would combining the relatively tiny errors of $\pm 1$ and $\pm 2$ possibly mean?

Comment: Still one would be more accurate than the other. No? Anyway, what would you suggest in case the data vary from 5 to 10?